# Authentication in python ldap

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, adfs, python-ldap

I have an ldap server who I connect to using `con = ldap.initialize(server)` and I bind to the server using `con.simple_bind_s(bind_dn, bind_password)`.

Now I want a authenticate a user using this ldap connection using his username and password which is different from the bind username and password. I searched a lot but didn't get any concrete answer.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 con.simple_bind_s(POST[bind_dn], POST[bind_password])
```

Can be used for both admin and users, something like this:

```
 con.simple_bind_s(uid=1000,ou=people,o=org, password)
 con.simple_bind_s(cn=Directory Manager, password)
```

In general, you can find ready to use modules in python that allow the management for users session using the same priciple, ceck this: https://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/ldap-auth.html

Comment: TypeError: simple_bind_s() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uid'

I get this error @hamza-tahiri

Comment: try  : con.simple_bind_s("uid=1000,ou=people,o=org", "password")

Comment: could be anything, a user can have cn, check the data you have on your ldap